# Identify blank tables in a database and insert data from another table on a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Actual Scenario**: I have a duplicate database and want to know in which tables data has not been moved from original database. Then I want to populate the Duplicate database tables from Original.

> I achieved my partial solution (i.e finding empty tables) writing the following script:

```
SELECT
    DBDupl.[dbo].sysobjects.Name, DBDupl.[dbo].sysindexes.Rows FROM
    DBDupl.[dbo].sysobjects
    INNER JOIN DBDupl.[dbo].sysindexes
    ON DBDupl.[dbo].sysobjects.id = DCT_SOURCE_QA.[dbo].sysindexes.id WHERE
    type = 'U'
    AND DBDupl.[dbo].sysindexes.IndId < 2 and rows= '0'
     EXCEPT

SELECT
    DBOrig.[dbo].sysobjects.Name, DBOrig.[dbo].sysindexes.Rows FROM
    DBOrig.[dbo].sysobjects
    INNER JOIN DBOrig.[dbo].sysindexes

    ON DBOrig.[dbo].sysobjects.id = DBOrig.[dbo].sysindexes.id WHERE
    type = 'U'
    AND DBOrig.[dbo].sysindexes.IndId < 2 and rows= '0'
```

Now I want to populate data in the tables which are empty. Is there a single query to do both the things i.e (1).Finding out which tables are left to be populated and (2). Populate the data from DBOrig to DBDupl. I have achieved (1) with the above script and don't want to insert data manually.

Comment: I've hacked together something in the past that simply generated a SQL `insert` statement for me that I simply needed to run; one thing to watch out for is identity columns though - remove the identity property first, and reinstate it afterwards.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, I have already created the duplicate database. All properties set, identity columns handled and reseeded. But I missed out on some columns while data transfer. Now I want to populate remaining columns only. If only you could tell me how the "Hack" worked..

Comment: Just to check, is it individual columns from otherwise complete rows that weren't transferred across, or the entire content of a few of the tables?

Comment: Entire content of the tables

Comment: In which case, I think was as simple as, considering I knew the table structures, `SELECT 'insert into DBDupl.dbo.myTable values (', id, ',''' + name + ''')' from DBOrig.dbo.myTable`. I then copied the output into another SQL window and ran it; it was a one-off job (as I suspect yours may be) so code quality and reusability was unimportant.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I already have a "set" of empty table names from the script I posted in the question. Just need to use them in my `insert` query.

Comment: Sounds more like a database synchronization tool is required. I think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

do you want an exact copy of the database? why not a backup of the main one and a restore with a different name?

If not possible, you can use SSIS to move the data or something like:

```
insert into destDB.dbo.mytable
select * sourcedb.dbo.mytable
```

you can use your script to loop through the empty tables and run some dynamic SQL to execute the command above

Answer (score 0):

Can you just:

1) Get a list of tables

2) For each of those tables, insert from one database to another

FYI - if you need to compare the databases, Visual Studio can do a schema/data compare and it's free

Here is a sample script. It assumes the table structures are the same.
You can either use print to generate a script or execute the commands (this is commented out)

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON 


DECLARE
    @objectName nvarchar(256)
    ,@sql nvarchar(max)
    ,@db1 nvarchar(100) = 'DB_1'
    ,@db2 nvarchar(100) = 'DB_2'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #EmptyTables


;WITH c_EmptyTables AS (
    SELECT t.object_id
        ,s.Name AS SchemaName
        ,t.Name AS TableName
        ,p.rows AS RowCounts
        ,FullName = CONCAT (
            QUOTENAME(s.name)
            ,'.'
            ,QUOTENAME(t.name)
            )
        ,CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.used_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Used_MB
        ,CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) / 128.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Unused_MB
        ,CAST(ROUND((SUM(a.total_pages) / 128.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS Total_MB
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID
        AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE ISNULL(p.rows, 0) = 0
    GROUP BY t.Name
        ,s.Name
        ,p.Rows
        ,t.object_id
)

SELECT *
INTO #EmptyTables
FROM c_EmptyTables

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT FullName
    FROM #EmptyTables t

OPEN cur 

FETCH NEXT 
FROM cur
INTO 
    @objectName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @db1 + '.' + @objectName + CHAR(10)
                + 'SELECT * FROM ' + @db2 + '.' + @objectName
                + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(10)

    PRINT(@sql)

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --EXEC(@sql)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        PRINT CHAR(10) + '*** UPDATE FAILED FOR ***';
        PRINT CHAR(10) + @sql
        PRINT CHAR(10)

        SELECT
             ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH


    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM cur
    INTO 
        @objectName
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```